# GIT - PHP - is it possible to read from GIT via API as data stream without saving into files first?

Tags: git, api, command-line, diff, data-stream

I need to read all files for a GIT branch (approx 10000 xml files) and then determine which has changed (since they have a Generated timestamp inside each file - I need to remove it first, then I'm able to identify if the file has changed or not compared to the previous release). - I wonder if there is GIT API enabling external scripts to read files as "data stream" - i.e. without having them to save as files first ?

Comment: You can ask git to provide any object with `git cat-file -p`. `git cat-file -p some-object-id` or `git cat-file -p some-branch:some/file/path.xml` or `git cat-file -p HEAD:path/to/file.xml`

Comment: Also consider the various --batch options with `git cat-file`.